# How to analyze price of air travel per mile distance

Tags: regression, mean

I'm trying to find the average price/mile for air travel. I found in an article that the average price is £35 + 7p or something and I wanted to know where that come from. I also wanted to ultimately prove that flying from the UK is cheaper than flying from someplace else.

How can you analyze price of air travel per distance? I was thinking of getting one way ticket prices from Google Flights and then copy this result to Excel and then dividing this price by the distance. Then I would take the 20th percentile and averaging this. I realize that this may not be not the best way. Any suggestion to how I should do this?

Comment: what is the goal of your analysis?

Comment: @mic Im trying to find the average price/mile for airplanes. I found in an article that the average price is £35 + 7p or something and i just wanted to know where that come from, and also ultimately proving that flying from UK is cheaper than flying from someplace else

Comment: You might maybe try a (gamma?) glm with log link and (log) distance as offset, search this site for use of [tag:offset]s